# Typing problems in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, typing, type-hinting

I have the following function:

```
def clock(dimS: Tuple[int] =(0)) -> Generator[Tuple[int], None, None]:
    """ Produce coordinates """
    itr = 0
    dim = len(dimS)
    maxItr = np.prod(dimS)

    if (dim < 1):
        raise ValueError(
            'function clock expected positive number of dimensions, received: 0'
        )

    while itr < maxItr:
        c = []
        ind = itr

        # build coordinate
        for i in range(dim):
            s = dimS[dim - i - 1]
            g = ind % s
            ind //= s       # update
            c.append(g)

        itr += 1
        yield tuple(reversed(c))
```

I'm using PyCharm to edit my code (love it). It tells me the type `Generator[Tuple[int], None, None]` was expected, but instead `got no return` ? When I change it to `Generator[Tuple[int], None, bool]` and add a line `return True`, as in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) example, the IDE highlights `True` and tells me `Expected Generator[Tuple[int], None, bool], got bool`. How do I fix this?

---

Here's a simpler example that does the same thing:

```
from typing import Generator

def foo(i: int =0) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    while True:
        i += 1
        yield i
```

It highlights `Generator[int, None, None]` and tells me `got no return`.

Comment: @AndrewLi I don't follow...

Comment: @AndrewLi Ahh yes, but then how is this function not similar then to the second example in the documentation? That doesn't `return` any value either, at least not with that keyword; they only specify the `YieldType` in `Generator` as `int` in the annotation. They talk explicitly about annotating the generator's return type annotation with `Generator`.

Comment: It's possible PyCharm doesn't handle generator types correctly - have you looked to see if there's an open issue? Tried a simpler example to ensure the handling is correct?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a simpler example that does the same thing (edited: I made a simple error but it still does the same thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mypy` accepts your sample input without issue. This is an issue with PyCharm from what it seems.

Scaning through the bug tracker for JetBrains, I found an issue that deals with what you're experiencing, see [Return type hint messes up with 'Generator' type](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-20709).

Comment: The issue states that it is fixed @bjd2385 Don't know how PyCharm development goes but I'm guessing that if you get the most recent build you'll get the expected results.

Comment: I downloaded it from their site and installed it, so I don't know how my version could be out of date.

Comment: @bjd2385 The fix was performed quite recently from what I can understand, most likely the build that contains the fix has not yet been released. Wait until the next build is released and if that *still* doesn't perform as expected you should raise an appropriate issue in their bug tracker.

Comment: Last night I was prompted by PyCharm to grab an update (popup in the lower-right) and it resolved this issue. Thank you for all of your help; it seems I was just one day ahead of the fix.

Comment: On an additional note, I checked out Mypy after attending PyCon and it's really useful!