# How to properly annotate generators to pass linters such as Pycharm's?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a pipeline of generators that feed into one another and are driven by a `csv.Dictwriter.writerows` function call at the end of the script.  Here is the pipeline:

```
chunks = (gen_issue_chunk(
        j,
        start,
        jql,
        expand='changelog',
        fields=desired_fields)
              for start in start_at)
    issues = gen_issues(chunks)

    # A set to collect all issue ID's that need to be removed from the db.
    to_delete = set()
    rows = process_issues(issues, to_delete)
```

In the `gen_issues` function, for example, here is what my function signature looks like:

```
def gen_issues(chunks) -> Generator[resources.Issue, None, None]:
    """


    :param chunks:
    :return:
    """
    for chunk in chunks:
        yield from chunk
```

This `Generator` type was imported from the `typing` module.  But then when this gets passed into the `process_issues` function, when I try to iterate through the issues I get a linter warning that `collections.Iterable` was expected, and instead received `Generator[...]`.  I'll also receive warnings when passing in this type when a function is expecting a `generator`, and it says the expected signature is `__generator[any, any, None]`.

What is the proper (best-practice) way to annotate generators?

Comment: You're not doing something wrong, PyCharms type checker is, from what I gather. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144086/typing-problems-in-pycharm/41144625#41144625) (though I don't think that's a dupe from what I can understand) for a similar issue. Best to check with their issue tracker on this.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, thanks for clearing that up!